# Find the longest blob prefix in a blob

Tags: c++, string, indexing, substr

I try to produce / get an efficient implementation in C++ for the following problem:

I have to blobs (const char *data, size_t length), i call them "blob1" and "blob2". Now i like to get the longest prefix of "blob2" in "blob1". If the longest prefix is multiple times in "blob1" i like to get the one which has the biggest index.

Here an example (the blobs are here just ASCII-strings, so it's easier to read the example):

blob1 = `HELLO LOOO HELOO LOOO LOO JU`

blob2 = `LOOO TUS`

The following are all valid prefixes of blob2:

{ `L`, `LO`, `LOO`, `LOOO`, `LOOO`, `LOOO T`, `LOOO TU`, `LOOO TUS` }

The longest prefix of `blob2` in `blob1` is `LOOO`. It is there twice:
`HELLO *LOOO *HELOO *LOOO *LOO JU`

So i like to get the index of the second one, which would be `6`, and the length of the prefix which would be `4`.

Unfortunately blob1 and blob2 change many times, so it is probably slow to create a tree or some other complex structure.

Do you know a good algorithm to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Cheers
Kevin

Comment: And, which algorithm have you tried so far?

Comment: sometimes I wish there was a nottried tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if this the best algorithm to solve this (I'm sure, this is not), but, I guess this is a good one. The idea is simple, start by searching for the lowest token from blob2 in blob1. When you find a match, try to see if you can match biggers tokens at this position. If this is true, update your token length.

Continue your search, from your last stop, but, at this time, searching for token with the updated token length from blob2. When you find a match, try to see if you can match biggers tokens at this position. If this is true, update your token length. Repeat the previous procedure until the end of your buffer.

Bellow is a simple fluxogram trying to explain this algorithm and, in sequence, a simple complete program, showing an implementation.

[image]

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

/////////////////////0123456789012345678901234567
const char str1[] = "HELLO LOOO HELOO LOOO LOO JU";
const char str2[] = "LOOO TUS";

int main()
{
  std::vector<char> blob1(strlen(str1));
  std::vector<char> blob2(strlen(str2));
  blob1.reserve(30);
  blob2.reserve(30);

  std::copy(str1, str1+strlen(str1), blob1.begin());
  std::copy(str2, str2+strlen(str2), blob2.begin());

  auto next = blob1.begin();
  auto tokenLength = 1;
  auto position = -1;

  while ( std::next(next, tokenLength) < blob1.end() ) {
    auto current = std::search(next, 
                               blob1.end(), 
                               blob2.begin(), 
                               std::next(blob2.begin(), tokenLength));

    if (current == blob1.end() )
      break;

    position = std::distance(blob1.begin(), current);
    next = std::next(current, 1);

    for (auto i = tokenLength; std::next(blob2.begin(), i) < blob2.end(); ++i) {
      auto x = std::search(std::next(current, i), 
                           std::next(current, i + 1), 
                           std::next(blob2.begin(), i), 
                           std::next(blob2.begin(), i + 1));
      if ( x != std::next(current, i) ) 
            break;

      ++tokenLength;
    }
  }

  std::cout << "Index: " << position << ", length: " << tokenLength << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That looks very well. I first thought about something like this, but i was not sure. Thank you for this perfectly described and great solution!:)